# Override timestamp attributes on an ActiveRecord model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have an ActiveRecord model User where I am overriding the timestamp attributes as follows:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def updated_at
    <some calculation>
  end

  def updated_at=
    <some calculation>
  end

  def created_at
    <some calculation>
  end

  def created_at=
    <some calculation>
  end
end
```

Everything works fine when I pass in those attributes explicitly on creation. I want to be able to do those calculations even on regular updates and creates.

Eg:

```
User.create
User.update_attributes(:not_timestamp_attributes => <some value>)
```

should also update the timestamps with the calculations.

Is there a best practice around this? I have Googled and I couldn't find anything on overriding timestamp attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best practice would be to let ActiveRecord handle updating those values for you.

But if you still need to do some sort of computation you could try adding some callbacks to `before_save` and `before_create` to explicitly do that, something like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save   :compute_updated_at
  before_create :compute_created_at, :compute_updated_at

  def created_at
    read_attribute(:created_at)
  end

  def created_at=(value)
    compute_created_at
  end

  def updated_at
    read_attribute(:updated_at)
  end

  def updated_at=(value)
    compute_updated_at
  end

  private

  def compute_updated_at
    write_attribute(:updated_at, Time.now + 1.month)
  end

  def compute_created_at
    write_attribute(:created_at, Time.now + 2.month)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a separate column for your calculated values and one for the system updated values using a `before_save` action and `ActiveRecord::Dirty`'s "column_changed?" method

```
before_save :calculate_created_at, if: :created_at_changed?

def calculate_created_at
  update_column(:calculated_created_at, created_at - 1.days)
end
```